# Copy a row to new sheet based on value in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google Script that copies rows from one Google Sheet into different sheets based on the value of a cell.

The cell value are states in the United States. The master spreadsheet has data from a registration form that is being imported into it all the time. When a new registration happens (and the data is imported into the master sheet), I'd like the script to run and copy that row of data into the appropriate state sheet.

Here's where I'm at:

1. Get master sheet
2. Find the last row
3. Get the value of the cell in the column "state"
4. Copy that row into one of 50 different sheets depending on what state it is.
5. Run the script every time the master sheet is updated (via an API).

Any help would be appreciated. I'm definitely a newbie when it comes to scripting and this is just hurting my head.

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
function myFunction() {

// Get Source Spreadsheet
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get Source Sheet from Spreadsheet
var source_sheet = source.getActiveSheet();

// Get Active Range from Sheet
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// Get the Value of the State Cell
var cellValue = Range.getCell(lastrow,3);

// Copy Last Row to Appropriate State Sheet
if ( cellValue == 'Alaska') {
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
    var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    target_sheet.appendRow(lastRow);
}
}
```

Comment: Is the registration form a Google Form?

Comment: No Sandy, the registration form is a Gravity Forms form that's being imported into Google Sheets via Zapier.

Comment: You may need to use a time based trigger that runs every "x" units of time.  I'm not sure how the update would trigger a script to run, or if it's possible.  If you aren't familiar with the troubleshooting tools, that's one of the best things you could learn.  [Link to Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)  You need to read all of that.

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
// Get Active Range from Sheet
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
```

The `getLastRow()` method returns an integer.  Then further down in your code, you are using the `lastRow` variable as the data for `appendrow()` which won't work;

```
target_sheet.appendRow(lastRow);
```

The code should probably be something like this:

```
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var lastRowOfData = source_sheet
  .getRange(source_sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, source_sheet.getLastColumn())
  .getValues();  //Returns a two dimensional array

var oneD_Array = lastRowOfData.join().split(","); //Creates a one D array
target_sheet.appendRow(oneD_Array);
```

The `appendRow()` method takes a one dimensional array.  The `getValues()` method returns a 2 Dimensional array, so it must be converted.   Because you are only getting one row of data, it's easy to convert.  The outer array only has one inner array.  The one inner array has all the cell values of the row.

Comment: WOW, Sandy Good, THANK YOU SO MUCH. I just have to ask, the method getRange, why does the data go last Row, then 1, then 1 again, then Last Column?

I was looking at the Google Script docs and it seems to go last row, last column, number of rows, number of columns.

Comment: There are 4 variations of `getRange()`.  For the one with 4 parameters, the first parameter is the row number of the row to START at.  The second parameter is the column to START at.  So, to get the last row, you need to start at the last row, and you probably want to start in column 1.  The third parameter is the number of rows to get.  You only want to get one row.  The last parameter is the number of columns to get.  The number of columns to get is the same as the number of the last column. (if you want to get all the columns).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer for what I came up with for the code:

```
function myFunction() {

// Get Source Spreadsheet
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get Source Sheet from Spreadsheet
var source_sheet = source.getActiveSheet();

// Get Last Row
var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();

// Get Last Column
var lastColumn = source_sheet.getLastColumn();

// Get Last Row of Data  
var lastRowOfData = source_sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();

// Creates a one dimensional array  
var oneD_array = lastRowOfData.join().split(",");

// Get the Value of the State Cell
var cellValue = source_sheet.getRange(2,7).getValue();


// Copy Last Row to Appropriate State Sheet
if ( cellValue == "New York" ) {
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
    var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    target_sheet.appendRow(oneD_array);
}
```

}